# Centreon 23.04, Update host via API

Tags: centreon-api

it's possible to edit host details via Centreon 23.04 API? Especially i would like to update GPS coordinates.

I reead documentation centreon API v2 and look on relative Postman collection but i not found any endpoint to host update.
I'm not here to find the code but just to find necessary endpoint and relative info. Thanks.